# CSS flex end by default when only one item in container

Tags: css

I have a container that uses flex like a navbar so i have left and right items using space between property. My issue is that sometimes the left items are non existent and I would like the  right items to stay on the right side still. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/Lnwzgm7f/1/) is an example:

```
<div class="container">
  <div>
  Stay on left
  </div>
  
  <div>
  Stay on right
  </div>
</div>

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

When I remove the stay on left div I still need the stay on right div to stay on the right side of the container

Comment: use margin-left: auto on your second element

Comment: @TemaniAfif this is the correct answer I was looking for!

Answer (score -1):

```html
    <div class="container">
  <div>
  Stay on right
  </div>
  
  <div>
  Stay on left
  </div>
</div>

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Comment: When they are both in the container it is reverse

Comment: Not if the the "stay on left" div is placed after the "Stay on right" div. the main idea is to keep the div to the right when one of both is removed